# I can't load a complete url image with Imagick (error ssl)

Tags: php, imagick

I have several sites on a debian 8 with php 5.6 that load external photos using the Imagick library

I have this error that appeared today when i load a photo whith

```
<?php $image = new Imagick('https://monsite.com') ?>



PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Imagick::__construct(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:\nerror:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed' in
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Upgrade your OS. There was a root certificate expiry today that affects old versions of OpenSSL accessing LetsEncrypt sites. Debian 8 is hella old.

Comment: I can't update my OS easily because i have many sites in production and I cannot afford to break configuration with update.
I migrate my sites one by one on a new server and it takes time

Comment: Can I try adding trusted root certificates to the server ?

https://manuals.gfi.com/en/kerio/connect/content/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/adding-trusted-root-certificates-to-the-server-1605.html

Comment: No. The problem is that LetsEncrypt's chain is cross-signed by an expired cert in the _existing_ trusted roots, and old versions of OpenSSL don't move past it to see the other _valid_ root that's already there. Adding another one isn't going to help. [There are potential workarounds](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2021/09/13/LetsEncryptRootCertExpire/) but YMMV and I still maintain that running an EOL OS in production is a resume-generating event.